# Wordpress posts not showing after certain time of day?

Tags: php, wordpress, timing

I've got a weird issue, possibly because I've customized some PHP on my Wordpress site.

I've got a template called homepage.php that displays all the posts from today's date (taken directly from the Wordpress Codex, filed under WP_Query).

About 7 or 8PM every day, all the posts disappear from that page. Why? And how do I fix it?

I thought at a certain point that it might be a post expiration issue, but I never set any expiration - I don't even think that's an included feature in Wordpress, is it?

Many thanks.

Full code included below just in case there's some clue here.

```html
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Home Page
* The template for displaying all of today's posts on home page.
*
* This is the template that displays only today's posts.
* Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages and that
* other "pages" on your WordPress site will use a different template.
*
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage Twenty_Fifteen
* @since Twenty Fifteen 1.0
*/

get_header(); ?>

<?php
$today = getdate();
$query = new WP_Query( 'year=' . $today['year'] . '&monthnum=' . $today['mon'] . '&day=' . $today['mday'] );
?>  

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
  <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

    <?php
// Start the loop.
if ($query->have_posts() )
{
echo'<ul>';
while ( $query->have_posts() ){
$query->the_post();     
echo '<li>' . get_template_part('content', get_post_format() ) . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';


/* Restore Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
//else : // no posts found. 

}
?>

  </main><!-- .site-main -->
</div><!-- .content-area -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: I think is a Timezone problem !

Comment: I checked my timezone, it's set to eastern time, which I'm in. Am I doing it wrong? Is there a timezone feature I'm not utilizing in the PHP?

Comment: Greenwich mean time is 4 hours ahead of eastern Time: 8PM + 4 = 00:00 (next Day) and don't forget the Summer Time. So `getdate()` returns GMT time ! Try to check Timezone setting in the wordpress admin section (Settings).

Comment: Excellent! Thanks!